# D3-v4 Rescaling brush on zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a timeline where the time axis has zoom enabled and the chart area is brushable. My current issue is that the brush won't scale and translate properly with the zoom. The problem is on line 118 of http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/c396227fba00637e6e1f3290934ae83a 
I know that the current code just resets the brush to the whole x-range scaled by the transform but even when zooming the brush does not even scale properly. I can't work out the math for rescaling the brush that is in pixel-space.

Comment: I now have translation working but zoom is still not properly working
http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/760ad1e9706f07a7b7f9f50b4c0b9a07

Comment: Zoom was broken due to brush being added to svg and not chartWrapper.
http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/3eae58d2a1742d238f68187463b713ee